# XML find value under specific element

Tags: c#, xml

I need a method that has one input argument (aPath) and a boolean return value.
I want to check if the input is under "Mandatory" element.
For instance: IsMandatory(@"\documents");

this is the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <strategy>
  <mandatory>
  <path>\\documents</path>
  <path>\\movies</path>
  <path>\\sounds</path>
  </mandatory>
  <optional>
  <path>\\images</path> 
  </optional>
  <ignored /> 
  </strategy>
```

Comment: What is a sample `aPath` input? And is it *deliberately* using C# verbatim string literal syntax inside xml?

Comment: Why do you have `@`'s in your XML?

Comment: its aPath ... like "\documents" ... it could be anything (string)... i just need to check if the input is under mandatory ... then i need another method to check if its under optional, ignored ... there i edited the code.

Comment: Also; xml is case-sensitive - there **is** no "Mandatory" element (question); sorry to be picky, but in the case of xml: it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
bool exists = XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("mandatory")
       .Elements("path").Any(p => p.Value == aPath);
```

Note that with the content in the **origianl** question, this will return true for:

```
string aPath = @"@""\documents\""";
```

which is to say, a string with the internal value `@"\documents\"`

Comment: i like this aproach, but i get error: Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

Comment: @no9 - what is the context? What version of .NET etc? That should be OK on .NET 3.5 and above...

Comment: .NET 4 ... there must be something wrong with xml ... if i ony do XElement.Parse(@"D:\test.xml") i get "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: @no9 in that case you mean `.Load("d:\test.xml")`

Comment: After all, `d:\test.xml` isn't an xml string... The file **at** `d:\test.xml` may be though

Comment: generaly this works .. but if my input is "\\documents\\folder1\\" and in xml under mandatory path value is also "\\documents\\folder1\\" the code returns false. If i change input and value in xml to "test" the code returns true. Why is that?

Comment: @no9 - a C# literal of `"\\documents\\..."` represents the *string* with content `\documents\ `, since ` \\ ` is the escape-sequence for ` \ `. If you use a *verbatim* string literal `@"\\documents\\..."` then it should work as expected. The `@` prefix is the important difference here.

Comment: thanx for all your time Marc!